# Как создать чистую модель для работы с БД?

Tags: php, symfony

Сейчас работаю с symfony, меня интересует вопрос, как можно на этом фреймворке создать чистую модель для работы с бд (по принципу MVC), в которой можно было бы писать чистые sql запросы, а затем из контроллера вызывать методы модели? Как это на Laravel к примеру, т.е. там можно было реализовать полноценную MVC без всяких ORM и сущностей.

P.S. Вообще не пойму прикол ORM-ок, поэтому предпочитаю писать sql запросы, так удобнее.

Comment: Сами себе противоречите))) "модель", но "ненавижу ОРМ". "MVC", но "предпочитаю писать запросы" https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql

Comment: Под моделью я имею в виду отдельный класс для работы с бд, для разбиения логики приложения. Но уже в моделе хочу писать sql запросы.

Comment: Тогда с симфони вам скорей всего не по пути

Comment: Ну так не используйте доктрину, а создайте собственный класс-сервис, whatever и используйте его, при чем тут симфони.

Comment: Странная постановка вопроса, но скорее всего подойдет использование кастомных классов репозитория. Почитать можно тут https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/repository.html

Comment: Посмотрите как реализовано в Java myBatis. Сделайте или найдите аналог на php

Answer (score 0):

Небольшой пример, безусловно не претендует на гениальность и чтобы использовать в продакшене, нужно поработать

src/Models/AbstractModel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

/**
 * Class AbstractModel
 * @package App\Models
 */
abstract class AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var \mysqli
     */
    protected $mysql;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $host;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $database;

    /**
     * AbstractModel constructor.
     *
     * @param string $host
     * @param string $user
     * @param string $password
     * @param string $database
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function __construct(string $host, string $user, string $password, string $database)
    {
        $this->host     = $host;
        $this->user     = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->mysql = $this->getConnection();
    }

    /**
     * @return \mysqli
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function getConnection(): \mysqli
    {
        $connection = new \mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database);
        if ($connection->connect_error) {
            throw new \Exception('Connect Error (' . $connection->connect_errno . ') ' . $connection->connect_error);
        }
        return $connection;
    }
}
```

src/Models/TestModel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

/**
 * Class TestModel
 * @package App\Models
 */
class TestModel extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAll(): array
    {
        return $this->mysql->query('select * from test_table')->fetch_all();
    }

    /**
     * insert new new
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function add(string $name): bool
    {
        return $this->mysql->query("insert into test_table (name, createdAt) VALUES ('$name', NOW())") === true;
    }

    /**
     * update a record
     *
     * @param int    $id
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update(int $id, string $name): bool
    {
        return $this->mysql->query("update test_table set name='$name' where id = '$id'") === true;
    }

    /**
     * delete a record
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function delete(int $id): bool
    {
        return $this->mysql->query("delete test_table where id = '$id'") === true;
    }
}
```

config/services.yaml

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: symfony
    database_password: symfony

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones


    App\Models\AbstractModel:
        abstract: true
        arguments:
            - '%database_host%'
            - '%database_user%'
            - '%database_password%'
            - '%database_name%'
        public: true

    App\Models\TestModel:
        parent: App\Models\AbstractModel
        public: true
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: false
```

Ну и контроллер, для полноты примера
src/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Models\TestModel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

/**
 * Class DefaultController
 * @package App\Controller
 */
class DefaultController
{
    private $testModel;

    public function __construct(TestModel $testModel)
    {
        $this->testModel = $testModel;
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        return new JsonResponse($this->testModel->getAll());
    }
}
```